# How to add pagination in Angular 4 for a table?

Tags: html, angular, html-table, pagination

I am new to Angular 4 and I would appreciate if somebody could tell me how I can add pagination in a table.
Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="tableDiv && adv1" id="adv1Div">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="adv1Table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="black-muted-bg" >
                        <th class="align-right" *ngFor="let data of calendarTable[0].weeks">{{data.period}}</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="no-top-border" *ngFor="let item of calendarTable| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 9, currentPage: p };">
                        <td contenteditable='true' *ngFor="let data of item.weeks| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 9, currentPage: p };" class="align-right">{{data.price}}</td>   
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    {{p}}
                  </a>

            </table>

        </div>
```

And my JSON is :

```
 public calendarTable = [
      { name: "TV AD1", 
          weeks: [
          { period: "2/10/2017", price: "400" },
          { period: "9/10/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "16/10/2017", price: "200" },
          { period: "23/10/2017", price: "500" },
          { period: "30/10/2017", price: "600" },
          { period: "6/11/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "13/11/2017", price: "700" },
          { period: "20/11/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "27/11/2017", price: "900" },
          { period: "4/12/2017", price: "400" },
          { period: "11/12/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "18/12/2017", price: "200" },
          { period: "25/12/2017", price: "500" },
          { period: "1/1/2018", price: "600" },
          { period: "8/1/2018", price: "800" },
          { period: "15/1/2018", price: "700" },
          { period: "22/1/2018", price: "800" },
          { period: "29/1/2018", price: "900" }
          ]

          }
   ]
```

I want to add 5 items per page in a table. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Simply limit your `*ngFor` to print 5 by 5 rows ?

Comment: You can try with Angular Datatable: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Comment: Check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-table

Answer (score 21):

A simple solution with ngx-pagination installed for Angular 4 can be found [here](https://ciphertrick.com/2017/08/01/search-sort-pagination-in-angular/).  All you need is to import it to your ngModule and declare the page index in your component.ts as `p: number = 1;`.

Locate your pagination element under your table as shown below:

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

Declare the number of row to be shown in your *ngFor //:

```
<tr *ngFor="let game of games | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: this was a very simple solution, much appreciated!

Comment: @Mnemo , For me same content is repeating in each page.Please help.

Comment: @ADARSHK can you please elaborate more or show it in plunkr? This is likely due to your array data issue, not pagination problem.

Comment: @Mnemo,I Made a question with description of details I have in this issue .I will share the link.Please review and help for a solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/59316363/9493078

Answer (score 3):

you can check a tutorial [here](http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-apply-search-sort-and-pagination-in-angularjs-example-using-dir-pagination-controls)

and you can find the demo [here](http://demo.expertphp.in/search-sort-and-pagination-angularjs-example/)

Update :- 
check [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google)

**UPDATE 2 :-**

The above tutorial actually have this base logic:-
1). max 10 links are shown at once.
2). active like is 6th position if active page if above 5 or below 4 from last position.

> pagination logic(added as a service to be able to reuse) :-

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export class PagerService {
    getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) {
        // calculate total pages
        let totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        let startPage: number, endPage: number;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        let pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
}
```

> Component which use the pagination service :-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import * as _ from 'underscore';

import { PagerService } from './_services/index'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: Http, private pagerService: PagerService) { }

    // array of all items to be paged
    private allItems: any[];

    // pager object
    pager: any = {};

    // paged items
    pagedItems: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        // get dummy data
        this.http.get('./dummy-data.json')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                // set items to json response
                this.allItems = data;

                // initialize to page 1
                this.setPage(1);
            });
    }

    setPage(page: number) {
        if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }

        // get pager object from service
        this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.allItems.length, page);

        // get current page of items
        this.pagedItems = this.allItems.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

> The HTML Template:-

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>Angular 2 - Pagination Example with logic like Google</h1>

            <!-- items being paged -->
            <div *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">{{item.name}}</div>

            <!-- pager -->
            <ul *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update 3:-**
A simpler approach...though i provided a single button with toggle logic which you can change it with multiple buttons

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template:`
                    <div> 
                         <h5>TV ADS</h5>

                                <ul>
                                  <li *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected.weeks">
                                   <span>{{item.period}}</span>
                                  </li>
                                </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button (click)="update()">change</button>
                    </div>
                 `
    })
    export class SomeComponent {
              public calendarTable = [
      { name: "TV AD1", 
          weeks: [
          { period: "2/10/2017", price: "400" },
          { period: "9/10/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "16/10/2017", price: "200" },
          { period: "23/10/2017", price: "500" },
          { period: "30/10/2017", price: "600" },
          { period: "6/11/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "13/11/2017", price: "700" },
          { period: "20/11/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "27/11/2017", price: "900" },
          { period: "4/12/2017", price: "400" },
          { period: "11/12/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "18/12/2017", price: "200" },
          { period: "25/12/2017", price: "500" },
          { period: "1/1/2018", price: "600" },
          { period: "8/1/2018", price: "800" },
          { period: "15/1/2018", price: "700" },
          { period: "22/1/2018", price: "800" },
          { period: "29/1/2018", price: "900" }
          ]
      },
      { name: "TV AD2", 
          weeks: [
            { period: "2/10/2017", price: "500" },
            { period: "9/10/2017", price: "600" },
            { period: "16/10/2017", price: "700" },
            { period: "23/10/2017", price: "800" },
            { period: "30/10/2017", price: "900" },
            { period: "6/10/2017", price: "100" },
            { period: "13/10/2017", price: "200" },
            { period: "20/10/2017", price: "300" },
            { period: "27/10/2017", price: "400" },
            { period: "4/12/2017", price: "400" },
            { period: "11/12/2017", price: "800" },
            { period: "18/12/2017", price: "200" },
            { period: "25/12/2017", price: "500" },
            { period: "1/1/2018", price: "600" },
            { period: "8/1/2018", price: "800" },
            { period: "15/1/2018", price: "700" },
            { period: "22/1/2018", price: "800" },
            { period: "29/1/2018", price: "900" }
            ]
          },

      { name: "TV AD3",
          weeks: [
            { period: "2/10/2017", price: "500" },
            { period: "9/10/2017", price: "600" },
            { period: "16/10/2017", price: "700" },
            { period: "23/10/2017", price: "800" },
            { period: "30/10/2017", price: "900" },
            { period: "6/10/2017", price: "100" },
            { period: "13/10/2017", price: "200" },
            { period: "20/10/2017", price: "300" },
            { period: "27/10/2017", price: "400" },
            { period: "4/12/2017", price: "400" },
            { period: "11/12/2017", price: "800" },
            { period: "18/12/2017", price: "200" },
            { period: "25/12/2017", price: "500" },
            { period: "1/1/2018", price: "600" },
            { period: "8/1/2018", price: "800" },
            { period: "15/1/2018", price: "700" },
            { period: "22/1/2018", price: "800" },
            { period: "29/1/2018", price: "900" }
            ]
          },

      { name: "TV AD4",
        weeks: [
          { period: "2/10/2017", price: "500" },
          { period: "9/10/2017", price: "600" },
          { period: "16/10/2017", price: "700" },
          { period: "23/10/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "30/10/2017", price: "900" },
          { period: "6/10/2017", price: "100" },
          { period: "13/10/2017", price: "200" },
          { period: "20/10/2017", price: "300" },
          { period: "27/10/2017", price: "400" },
          { period: "4/12/2017", price: "400" },
          { period: "11/12/2017", price: "800" },
          { period: "18/12/2017", price: "200" },
          { period: "25/12/2017", price: "500" },
          { period: "1/1/2018", price: "600" },
          { period: "8/1/2018", price: "800" },
          { period: "15/1/2018", price: "700" },
          { period: "22/1/2018", price: "800" },
          { period: "29/1/2018", price: "900" }
            ]
          }
   ]
        calendarTableSelected: Array;
        i: number= 0;
        constructor() {
            this.calendarTableSelected = this.calendarTable[0];
        }
        update(){
            if(this.i == 0){this.i = 1;}else{this.i = 0}// change this acc. to your needed logic or use any of the above provided links to form your logic
            this.calendarTableSelected = this.calendarTable[this.i];
        }

    }
```

**[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AOEV57eCwEGSCb6qxxKZ?p=preview)** as requested.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it will not work in Angular4.

Comment: hehe i thought u'll get the idea by it..give me awhile...i'll provide the code... i'll update the answer.... i am out actually..

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17661864)

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you... i am still out.. i'll do it once i be back home :) i planned to do it anyways ^_^

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Hi Himanshu.Thank you for looking into this. But none of the updates are working for me. Could you provide a working example of the same in jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: @NehaUniyal sure i'll provide it after my office hours... :)

Comment: @NehaUniyal check the plunkr.. https://plnkr.co/edit/AOEV57eCwEGSCb6qxxKZ?p=preview

Comment: I cannot understand from where the initial value of `totalItems` is set in `PagerService`?

Comment: `this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.allItems.length, page);` Check the pagerService in Appcomponent @bubble-cord

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Thanks for pointing. Sorry I din't gave it a proper look earlier.

Comment: @bubble-cord no problem ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular DataTable, if you want.

For documentation:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Comment: Thank you for your response. But that solution is for providing pagination to table rows. Is there any known property of pagination that I can apply for columns.