# table written in vanilla typescript. havent used any plugin or widget.want to add pagination to that table.I dont want to use any plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have a data table hard coded in my ts and html file. i want to add pagination and search functionality without using any plugin or widgets. can someone please tell me the logic how to implement it? i have hardcoded the table and have not used in plugins.

Answer (score 0):

you could use many plugins available on the web for angular . however you can get help from below url.
[How to add pagination in Angular 4 for a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806231/how-to-add-pagination-in-angular-4-for-a-table)

Comment: dont need no plugins